# Force reject/resolve promise

Tags: angularjs, q, jszip

I'm trying to validate a file upload by reading the contents of a manifest file within a zip file. I'm using JSZip to read the file and would like to stop the process of uploading the file under certain conditions. What's the correct way to force a resolve/reject with if/else?

```
  function validateUpload(file, errFiles) {
    var validateFile = JSZip.loadAsync(file)
    .then(function(zip) {
      var manifest = zip.files['manifest.json'];
      return manifest.async("text") // added return here
      .then(function(contents) {
        var manifestObj = angular.fromJson(contents);
        if((manifestObj.module === 'analytics') && ($state.current.name.indexOf('packages') !== -1)) {
          return $q.reject('Invalid software upload');
        }
        if(!manifestObj.module && ($state.current.name.indexOf('analytics') !== -1)) {
          return $q.reject('Invalid analytics upload');
        }
        return $q.resolve(file);
      });
    });
    validateFile.then(function(data) {
      console.log('success: ' + data);
      uploadFile(file);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('error: '+ error);
    });
```

***Edit***

I was missing a return statement before the call to manifest.async, seems to be correctly calling success/error of validateFile promise now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a return statement before the call to manifest.async fixed the issue.